# Update ASp.net gridvidew without postback without update panel!

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

Is there any solution to update asp.net gridview without postback and withput update panel?
or update partial page without update panel?
for example with jquery.
thanks

Comment: http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/04/GridView-Grouping-Master-Detail-Drill-Down-Using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure,

- Javascript & Web Services
- Javascript & calling a method on the same web page

Here's a post about using JQuery
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx